# Change line break characters in HTML

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, line-breaks

In Firefox a '/' breaks a line, but in chrome the line continues. How can I tell chrome to allow a line break on '/'?

This is a problem for the middle table on

http://webnumbr.com/api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could surround the '/' with Unicode Zero-Width space characters. (For the links, don't do it for the hrefs)

See here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS word wrap property:

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

Don't rely on special characters to break words.

Comment: Why not? You use special characters to not-break. (&nbsp;)

Comment: When copying and pasting text, special characters also get selected and can cause problems when trying to paste that text.  Think of selecting some text and then doing a search for that text somewhere else...  Those special characters can cause the word you're searching for to not be found correctly.